# I am trying to implement blog app with Django.I created registration form with profile pic upload.But its returning IntegrityError

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement blog app with Django.I created registration form with profile pic upload.But its returning integrity error null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7, pics/P_Wk6m1b3.png, null).

```
   #models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='pics')

#views.py
def register(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = Register(request.POST,request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
        profile = Profile()
        email = form.cleaned_data['Email']
        User_name=form.cleaned_data['Username']
        Password=form.cleaned_data['Password']
        Confirm_Password=form.cleaned_data['Confirm_Password']
        firstname=form.cleaned_data['Firstname']
        user=User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
                  password=Password,email=email,first_name=firstname)
        user.save();
        insert = Profile(image = request.FILES['picture'],
                                        user_id=request.user.id)
        insert.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = Register()
    return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})

  #forms.py
  class Register(forms.Form):
    Email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                           {"class":"inputvalues"}))
    Username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                           {"class":"inputvalues"}))
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
                                           ({"class":"inputvalues"})))
    Firstname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                              {"class":"inputvalues"}),max_length=30)
    Lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                              {"class":"inputvalues"}),max_length=40)
    Confirm_Password = forms.CharField
         (widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=({"class":"inputvalues"})))
    Image = forms.ImageField()

  def clean_Email(self):
   if validate_email(self.cleaned_data['Email']):
    raise forms.ValidationError("Email is not in correct format!")
   elif User.objects.filter(email = self.cleaned_data['Email'])
                                                   .exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError("Email aready exist!")
   return self.cleaned_data['Email']
  def clean_Username(self):
   if User.objects.filter(username = 
                    self.cleaned_data['Username']).exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exist!")
   return self.cleaned_data['Username']
  def clean_Confirm_Password(self):
   pas=self.cleaned_data['Password']
   cpas = self.cleaned_data['Confirm_Password']
   if pas != cpas:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Password and Confirm Password are not 
                                                 matching!")
   else:
    if len(pas) < 8:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password should have atleast 8 
                                                     character")
    if pas.isdigit():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password should not all numeric")

  <!-------register.html>
  {% extends 'layout.html' %}
  {% block content %}
  <div class="box">
    <h2>
        <center>Register</center>
    </h2><br>
    <form action='register' method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label class='labe'>Image:</label>
            {{ form.Image }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class='labe'>First name:</label>
            {{ form.Firstname }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class='labe'>Last name:</label>
            {{ form.Lastname }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class='labe'>Email:</label>
            {{ form.Email }}
            {{ form.Email.errors }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class='labe'>Username:</label>
            {{ form.Username }}
            {{ form.Username.errors }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class='labe'>Password:</label>
            {{ form.Password }}

        </div>
        <div>
            <label class='labe'>Confirm Password:</label>
            {{ form.Confirm_Password }}
            {{ form.Confirm_Password.errors }}
        </div>
        <input type="Submit" id="lg"/><br>
        <center><a href="login" >Already have an account.Login here. 
                                         </a></center>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>
    {% for message in messages%}
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

It returns integrity errorand i want to know what is that 7.It increases one by one if enter data and click on submit each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.user` is the currently logged in user. But there isn't a logged-in user, because this is the registration form. You need to use the user you just created.

```
    user=User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
              password=Password,email=email,first_name=firstname)
    insert = Profile(image = request.FILES['picture'],
                user=user)
    insert.save()
```

Comment: but in my profile model the foreign key is user_id if i use user = user it returns name user is not defined

Comment: As per the `Profile` model you shared, you have. a user field which is a `ForeignKey' to the `User` model. So, if you replace `user-id` with the `user` that's just created (and explained in this answer), it would work.

Comment: The profile model you posted above clearly shows a `user` field. If you're getting a name error, it's due a different reason. Update your question to show the new code and traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the user record in `register` but using request.user.id which i expect is None since the user hasn't logged in yet.

Instead just pass user directly :

```
insert = Profile(image = request.FILES['picture'], user=user)
```

Comment: but in my profile model the foreign key is user_id if i use user = user it returns name user is not defined

Comment: as you have defined in your post there is a Profile model with a `user` attribute - are you sure this is up to date ?

Comment: this is my profile model class Profile(models.Model):                                                 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='pics')